# JS написание кода, работающего на большинстве устройств

Tags: javascript

Написал небольшую вставку для форума на JS для вывода диалога в popup и отправке данных на сервер через AJAX.

Первая версия была сделана на fetch+promice.
Народ стал писать - у меня не запускается.

Переписал на jquery (3), убрал let, вставил var

Некоторое время было тихо.
Сегодня человек пишет - у меня планшет, Adnroid, Opera, не работает.

Честно говоря я в полной растерянности. Что там еще может остаться несовместимого в 100 строках JS кода. Последнее предположение - не поддерживается Formdata, но его поддержка заявлена в Opera с 2012 года.

Расскажите пожалуйста - **как Вы решаете проблемы совместимости ?**

Неужели мне придется подключать babel+webpack из за 100 строк кода?
Посоветуйте пожалуйста какие нибудь статьи на этот счет.

Ниже привел тот самый злополучный код.

```
var photobtn = document.querySelector("img[src$='bbc/photos.gif']");
photobtn.addEventListener('click',photoHandler);

function photoHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById("popup-container-background").style.display='block';

}

function insertMetachars(sStartTag) {
    var
        oMsgInput = document.getElementById('message'),
        nSelStart = oMsgInput.selectionStart,
        nSelEnd = oMsgInput.selectionEnd,
        sOldText = oMsgInput.value;

    if (nSelStart > sOldText.length) {
        nSelStart = sOldText.length;
        nSelEnd = nSelStart;
    }
    if ( nSelStart < 0) {
        nSelStart=0;
        nSelEnd=0;
    }
    oMsgInput.value = sOldText.substring(0, nSelStart) +
        sStartTag +
        sOldText.substring(nSelEnd);
    oMsgInput.setSelectionRange(nSelStart + sStartTag.length,nSelStart + sStartTag.length);
    oMsgInput.focus();
}

// Вставить полученные строки в редактор
function InsertToEditor(return_files) {
    var comments=document.getElementById('comment').value;
    comments = comments ? comments : '';
    var insText='[url=' + return_files['1600'] + '][img]'+return_files['350']+'[/img]'+comments+'[/url]'+'\n';

    insertMetachars(insText);
    ClearSendFormData();
    document.getElementById("popup-container-background").style.display='none';
}

function ClearSendFormData() {

    document.getElementById('comment').value='';
    document.getElementById('file-dialog-name-id').value='';
    document.getElementById('file-dialog').value= null;

}

// Ниже идет код для вставки send_pictures.html

function sendfile() {
    // если файл не выбран
    if ( document.getElementById('file-dialog').files.length == 0 ) return;


    // данные не должны попасть в POST
    // document.getElementById('comment').setAttribute('disabled','true');
    // document.getElementById('file-dialog-name-id').setAttribute('disabled','true');
    // var formData = new FormData(document.forms.send_to_google);

    var formData = new FormData();
    var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file-dialog');
    formData.append('file',fileSelect.files[0],fileSelect.files[0].name);

    var url_ajax = 'https://woodtoolsimg.ru/resize/gcs.php';

    $.ajax({
        url: url_ajax,
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        crossDomain : true,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            InsertToEditor(data);
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "Ошибка отправки фото на сервер" );
    });
}

function InsertContent(html) {

    document.getElementById("63096767-54D9-4EB4-B758-ECCE1FCF316D").innerHTML = html;
    document.getElementById('btnFrmGcs5').addEventListener('click', sendfile);
    document.getElementById('btnFrmGcs5_cancel').addEventListener('click', ()=>  document.getElementById("popup-container-background").style.display='none' );
    document.getElementById('5598de70-9f5a-11ea-bb37-0242ac130002').setAttribute('src',smf_theme_url + "/images/photo/comment.svg",)
}

// после загрузки photo.js выполнить код
function ready() {
    $.get(
            smf_theme_url + "/scripts/send_picture.html",
             function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                 InsertContent(data);
            }
        )
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "Ошибка получения шаблона" );
        });

}

ready();
```

asd

Comment: Если уже используете jQuery, то используйте везде и тогда можете забыть про проблемы с совместимостью. Если хотите знать какая фича поддержуется какая нет - https://caniuse.com/

Comment: Я уже избалован ES5, ES6, jquery не помню совсем. caniuse - конечно смотрел - не нашел ничего "запрещенного"

Comment: Если хотите писать на es6 + чтобы была совместимость, тогда используйте babel + сборщик (webpack или parcel попроще) + polyfills